# Broken thumbnails for 1-bit (2-color) cursors

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, cursor, mouse-cursor

Anytime I want to view or edit my cursors, I'd like to keep them in folders. However, when I try to view 1-bit cursors (2 colors), the thumbnail previews generated for these cursors are random things, such as programs, shortcuts, icon files, and other cursors. The thumbnails are different when viewing the folder with details/small icons or regular icons/content. I need these previews to see what cursor I'm trying to open/edit. When opening the file in Properties, it shows yet another random thumbnail, but completely black; however, it does show what cursor it is, but only visible on the black part of the thumbnail.

[image]
[image]

I'm the only user using the device. It happens regardless of which version of Windows I use (7, 10 and 11 are the ones I tested for this).

I tried restarting Explorer, clearing icon cache in Winaero Tweaker, duplicating the cursor and deleting the old one, and it keeps generating more random thumbnails. Another thing is that renaming a cursor to an existing file in the same folder changes the thumbnail to the one in said original file.

How can I make the thumbnails preview the exact cursor? Or is it just a problem with explorer.exe itself?